# Ruby Controller Views Actions and Model setup

Tags: ruby

I have been coding in php for a year now and i have recently decided to start learning Ruby because i heard its a better web language. I'm trying to convert what i have on the website  so far into Ruby code, but I'm having trouble understanding the structure for controllers views and models. Heres what i have for php pages.

Homepage(controller)

```
- index page

- about page

- etc.
```

Signup(controller)

```
- index page for signup
```

Signin(controller)

- index page for signin

Admin Page(controller)

Business Page(controller)

Do i make all these controllers and what do the actions and models represent? Is the action  the form to signup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd start from square one.  Learn how to make a simple blog-type application with rails to familiarize yourself with the MVC pattern (if you don't already know it) and get a feel for it.  that way, you'll have a better understanding of how it should be designed.

Comment: Andrew Perk did a very excellent simple series which helped get me started.  (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAC08CE3187BC75F1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try my best to give a condensed answer. RoR follows the MVC pattern (Model, View, Controller) typically controllers handle url requests, models store data and views are used to display the data to the end user. To answer your question, you would not need to create seperate controllers for each individual action. Controllers contain methods for creating, reading, updating, deleting (CRUD) and much more. For example: You might have a UsersController, within this controller are four methods; create, new, update, and delete. This would give you a URL something like /users/new  /users/1/edit  /users/1/delete

An application like the one you give as an example is quite simple. to seperate an "admin" page is simple and would be something like

`<%= if current_user.admin? %>`

content only the admin can see

`<% end %>`

Creating users would involve storing their details in the database, creating a session and allowing users to create and destroy sessions when they login and logout.

The major difference between RoR and PHP (to me, anyway) is PHP makes the views messy by embedding logic code directly into the .html page. Ruby on Rails provides a clean way of seperating logic from html content making it easier to manage or develop between a group.

Pages such as the root page, and about page or contact page might all be methods in the `HomeController` and would be accesible via `/home/index` `/home/about` `/home/contact`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

The above link would be the best place to start learning about the fundamentals.

Comment: very well answered exactly what i need to know thanks +1

Comment: No problem. I forgot to mention that RoR has a built in feature that changes `/home/contact.html.erb` to `/home/contact` in the route file. For example, `get '/home/contact', to: 'home#contact'` is a route that would redirect URL requests for `/home/contact` to the **contact** method in the **HomeController** (which in turn would display the `/app/views/home/contact.html.erb` file)  I mention this because I've used PHP before and (unless something new has come out) I don't think there are any solutions as simple as what RoR offers.

Comment: so in the routes file i should put get 'home#contact'

Comment: yes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html will give you more information about routing in RoR

Comment: if i go to localhost:3000/contact isn't that supposed to work because it replaced localhost:3000/home/contact. However it gives me no route matches

Comment: If you have a `contact` method in the `HomeController` but just wanted the route to be `/contact` you would need to do this instead: `get '/contact', to: 'home#contact'`